# eslint on dynamically changing file list

Tags: javascript, webpack, eslint, babel-loader, eslint-loader

I'd like to run `eslint` on modified files only. I've created a new run target in `package.json` to run `eslint` from command line (`git diff --name-only --relative | grep -E '.*\\.(vue|js)$' | xargs eslint --ext .js,.vue`). In theory, this should work fine, but there's a little transformation step happening in my project (a string replacement) when bundling the files with webpack that will throw off `eslint` (some non-standard markup will be expanded to JS).

What are my options and how would I go about implementing them? For instance, could I execute a particular webpack rule/loader and pipe the result to `eslint`? Another option I see is to include `eslint` into the webpack rule/loader process (instead of executing it from the command line), but how would I then filter on files that are currently modified (could this be handled by a temporary file that contains the `git diff...` result?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a somewhat working approach. I chose to modify `webpack.base.conf.js` instead of going for the command line solution to make use of the already existing string replacement loader.

The files are collected in the `WebpackBeforeBuildPlugin` callback function and instead of a regex based test variable, a function is used which checks against the previously collected files.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const WebpackBeforeBuildPlugin = require('before-build-webpack');
var modFilesList = new Set([]);
const srcPath = resolve('.');

...
      rules: [{
        test: function(filename) {
          let relFilename = path.relative(srcPath, filename);
          let lint = modFilesList.has(relFilename);
          return lint
        },
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        include: resolve('src'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter'),
          cache: false
        }
      }, {
       ... other string replacement loader ...
      }


   plugins: [
    ...
    new WebpackBeforeBuildPlugin(function(stats, callback) {
      // Collect changed files before building.
      let gitCmd = 'git diff --name-only --relative | grep -E ".*\\.(vue|js)$"';
      const proc = exec(gitCmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (stdout) {
          let files = stdout.split('\n');
          modFilesList = new Set(files);
        }
        if (error !== null) {
          console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
        }
      });
      callback();
    })
  ]
```

The only problem at the moment is that when git file changes occur, they don't trigger a re-linting based on these file changes (i.e. new file is changed, or previously (before starting webpack-dev-server) changed file changes are discarded). I checked everything I could. The change is registered and stored in `modFilesList`, the test function is executed and returns true (for a new change in a previously unchanged file) or false in case the change was discarded. I also played with the `cache` option to no avail. It seems that at initial load, `eslint-loader` caches the files it will lint in future (don't know if that's a result of using a test function instead of a regex or also the case with the regex). Is anyone having an idea or has seen this before (eslint-loader not updating the file list)?

**Update**

This seems to be a problem with webpack (or one of the other loaders) as the eslint-loader isn't even executed when the file changed. The `test` function however is executed which is a bit weird. I don't fully understand how loaders work or how they play together, so there might be some other loader that is causing this...